# Entity Framework 4.0 Many-Many relationship Using Non-Primary Key

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-4, legacy-database

I am trying to build a generic repository using Entity Framework 4.0 using a legacy MS SQL database I have inherited. A pretty familiar scenario.

I need to add category information to a fairly long list of existing items.

The items can belong to several categories at the same time so I created an mapping table called **CategoryMapping**

[image: Database Diagram]

Unfortunately **SchemaDefinitionCode** is not unique and cannot be made into a Foreign Key (FK) in the database.

I have tried to add my own partial class to the DefinitionSchema entity but as it's not indexed, this has a severe performance hit. *Demo code for testing, I won't want to create a new context every time I load this*:

```
public partial class DefinitionSchema
{
    private MyEntities context;

    public IQueryable<Category> Categories
    {
        get
        {
            context = new MyEntities();

            var categories = context.Categories
                                             .Where(c => c.CategoryMappings
                                                .Where(m => m.SchemaDefinitionCode == this.SchemaDefinitionCode).Any());

            return categories;
        }
    }
}
```

I can then call a list of items like so:

```
var q = context.SchemaDefinitions
.Where(s => s.Categories
    .Where(c => c.Name == category)
    .Any()
 );
```

How can I link my tables and mapping in the most efficient manner without wiping out the existing database structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't work this way because EF doesn't support unique keys and `SchemaDefinitionCode` must be unique to form valid many-to-many relation with `Category`. If your `SchemaDefinitionCode` is not unique in `DefinitionSchema` table it can't be used as principal end in the relation with `CatagoryMapping`.  If it is unique you can use `SchemaDefinitionID` instead because no more then one Id will have the same code value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll go about it by changing the SchemaDefinitionCode to SchemaDefinitionId.